# My view doesn't display all my db.MyDB.include(object)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have a method in my controller :

```
    public ViewResult Index()
{
    var orderdetail = db.OrderDetails.Include(o => o.Product).Include(o => o.Pack).Include(o => o.Order);           
    return View(orderdetail);
}
```

My View :

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.Username)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name) 
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pack.Name)
</td>
```

In my view, it will show just the first include. So here, just my Product because Include(o => o.Product) is before my Include(o => o.Pack). If I put Pack first, it will display only my Pack. I want my view display both. How can i do this ?

Excuse me for my english and thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be calling `.ToList()` at the end of your query, you don't want to be passing an unevaluated query to your view.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but `return View(orderdetail.ToList())` don't change anything, same problem

Comment: It wasn't an answer to your question it was just a bit of general advice. Your code looks as though it should work, have you tried using strings instead of lambdas? e.g. `Include("Product").Include("Pack").Include("Order")`

Comment: Ok sorry, I had written well ToList, I simply copied my line wrong. I've try using strings but still nothing. I keep looking but like you said, it's seems right to me, I don't understand.

Comment: I am pretty sure EF supports multiple Includes on the same entity, would be a bit useless if it didn't. Perhaps it's a bug with method chaining, have you tried splitting them up? e.g. `orderDetail.Include(o => o.Product); orderDetail.Include(o => o.Pack); ...`.

Comment: The answer to this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113774/entity-framework-getting-objects-not-immediately-related

Comment: @KevinMain That's more related to querying multiple levels i.e. if `Product` had a related table and you wanted to pull that down as well. This question is related to pulling multiple tables on the same entity.

Comment: @James Agh, very true..missed that bit.

Comment: @Alternative I made a mistake in my previous comment, if your querying individual lines you need to make it `orderDetail = orderDetail.Include(o => o.Product); orderDetail = orderDetail.Include(o => o.Order); ...`

Comment: `public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var orderdetail = db.OrderDetails.Include(o => o.Pack); 
             orderdetail = db.OrderDetails.Include(o => o.Product);
            orderdetail = db.OrderDetails.Include(o => o.Order);
                    
            return View(orderdetail.ToList());
        }`                                                                This code works, thanks a lot James. I can't answered, if you want do it... Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can chain `Include` calls that way, you will have to build your query up explictly e.g.

```
db.OrderDetails.Include(o => o.Product);
db.OrderDetails.Include(o => o.Pack);
db.OrderDetails.Include(o => o.Order);
return View(db.OrderDetails);
```

Comment: Add `db.OrderDetails.include(..)`, with the name of var like this `orderDetail = orderDetail.Include(...)`  it doesn't works. Thanks